# What happens to SynchronizationContext when main thread terminates?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronizationcontext

I have two threads, main and another one that I created to do some work.
I don't understand what happens when I call originalContext.Post (SyncronizationContext of main thread) from that other thread, where some UI elements are updated, when main thread is already terminated ? Is this safe and why ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is of course not going to come to very good end.  It depends on the actual synchronization provider, there is more than one.  Trying to focus a bit on the common ones, WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext and WpfSynchronizationContext.  Both will flush any pending posts from the queue, they'll just disappear without a trace.  If you continue on posting then Winforms will throw an InvalidOperationException.  Wpf is more convoluted, it can set the DispatcherOperation.Status field to indicate that it didn't work.  But as near as I can tell, this field is not being observed by the context code so it should just fall in the bit-bucket silently.

Clearly you never want this to happen.  The simple workaround is Thread.IsBackground = true to let the CLR clean up the mess, it is not often desirable to let a program continue without a UI.